# How to send notification without having the user to register his email

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I have been reading about sending notifications to all my android users. I found Google Cloud Messaging (GCM). However this service doesnt really give what I want. The user who downloads my android will need to register his/her email ID before they can receive messages from my php server.

However I wish that anybody who downloads the server will just have the opportunity to receive notifications from my php server without having to go through the process of registering his email ID.

Please is there any service that can do just that or there is a way out?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used GCM, but I used [Parse](https://parse.com/) on my app. It's pretty simple, free, and it provides a nice interface to send your Push Notifications.
You only have to register your user to a channel (or none, and the default is *broadcast*) and the user doesn't need to do anything.

If you don't necessarily need to send your notifications from your server, that's a good solution. Check out [Parse's tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications) on Android to send Push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of GCM in your app can work independently of the email registration process, if you want to keep both. The moment a user runs your app for the first time, you can tell the app to register the device to the GCM service, inform your php server that you have registered, and immediately start listening for messages from your php server. All of that can be done behind the scenes, without the user knowing.

You can learn more about the GCM service (and the demo app) [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm).

Comment: My problem is how to do register the user behind scenes. Please is there any tutorials to registering the device behind the scenes on the client side. I would be much grateful.